# How do post a search string to google.com using c#?

Tags: c#, http, https

Here is my code

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Examples.System.Net
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main ()
            {
   // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 

                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

   // Set the Method property of the request to POST.

                request.Method = "POST";
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.

               string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
               byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);

   // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.

               request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

   // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.

               request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

   // Get the request stream.

               Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();

   // Write the data to the request stream.

               dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

   // Close the Stream object

               dataStream.Close ();

   // Get the response.

               WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();

   // Display the status.

               Console.WriteLine 
      (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

   // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.

               dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

   // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.

               StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);

   // Read the content.

               string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();

    // Display the content.

               Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);

    // Clean up the streams.

               reader.Close ();
               dataStream.Close ();
               response.Close ();
           }
        }
    }
```

This is the exception I am getting

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at Examples.System.Net.Program.Main()
```

Comment: What problems do you have with this code? Compile errors, runtime exceptions, unintended  behaviour?

Comment: with system.web dll you can use Response.Redirect(web page url)

Comment: I have added the exception I am getting. Please be precise and detailed, I am relatively new to c sharp networking.

Comment: use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect what your browser sends to Google when you do a search yourself. I'm pretty sure they don't allow you to scrape their page that easy.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. Rene. Now may I ask, Can i use this fiddler on other websites too?

Comment: Yes, you can. You might also see [if any of these questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+google+search+hasaccepted%3Ayes) are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in for example Chrome Dev Tools, you see that Google don't use `POST` for search queries. (And don't allow them at all)

To make a search using a `WebRequest`, use `GET` to the Url = `https://www.google.se/search?q=This is a test that posts this string to a Web server`.

Comment: Ah.It works like magic. After using GET on the URL? Will google return the resultant HTML code for the search results?

Comment: Looks like they return the full page result. If you want the search result via a API instead in Json, you can for example use their service Google Custom Seach: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: Thanks. Can I use a WebRequest to fill in text fields and click buttons in another website like Facebook.com?

Comment: You can use a WebRequest to trigger those events/posts etc that the button will cause when pushing them, impersonate the browsers behavior. But that is far more complex than your initial question!

Comment: Okay. Please explain to me in code C Sharpian. Should I ask another question or you can answer me in the comments here?

Comment: I would start reading up on this link on the basics, and then start making specific questions if you get stuck: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1041115/webscraping-with-csharp

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer comes with delay :-) but after spending lot of time to figure out how to send data using HttpWebRequest, the best solution, for google request and in general to me is to use Fiddler to inspect all the data, and paramethers sent from browser.
Fiddler will help you to verify what browser sends to the server, i.e. method used by the server, query string, and all the headers like user-agent, accept and possible body string, etc.
Spending some time to setup Fiddler and learn to use it will save you many headaches.